# XML Serialization, No Whitespace

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I have the following serialization method:

```
    Private Function SerializeData(ByVal data As cData) As String
        If data IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim xml_stream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim sr As StreamReader
            Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(cData))
            xml_stream = New MemoryStream()

            Try
                xs.Serialize(xml_stream, data)
                xml_stream.Position = 0

                sr = New StreamReader(xml_stream)
                Return sr.ReadToEnd()
            Finally
                If sr IsNot Nothing Then sr.Close()
                xml_stream.Close()
            End Try

        Else
            Return "No data"
        End If
    End Function
```

however it returns the xml the nested elements indented.  Is there a way to shut that off on the serializer, or do I need to just run a find replace routine to get rid of it all?

Essentially, what I want to see is:

```
<root><child1>data</child1><child2>data</child2></root>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Serialize override that accepts an XmlWriter parameter. Create the XmlWriter using XmlWriter::Create, passing in an XmlWriterSettings object with the Indent property set to false.